# create an input sheet with a submit button in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to make a sheet where on the first tab I can enter data, push submit button, and it transfer to the second tab to the lines corresponding to the Name in the first tab.
And after clicking submit, the data in first tab is cleared from the fields.

Is it possible to make it with a script?

[first tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irZgr.jpg)
[second tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUYMB.jpg)

I know this script can add all the values to the last row, but I'd like to find the correct row, and add data there

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet"); //Data Sheet

  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
             formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
             formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
             formSS.getRange("G10").getValue(),
             formSS.getRange("D12").getValue(),
             formSS.getRange("G12").getValue()]];

  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues(values);
}
```

How can I find the exact row that corrensponding to the name and add the values to this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, as a simple modification, how about using TextFinder? When this is reflected in your script, please modify your showing script as follows.

#### From:

```
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues(values);
```

#### To:

```
var range = datasheet.getRange("A2:A" + datasheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(values[0][0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
if (range) {
  range.offset(0, 0, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the value is searched from column "A" of the destination sheet and put the values to the searched row.
- When you want to add a new value when the search value couldn't be found in column "A" of the destination sheet, how about the following modification?

  ```
    var range = datasheet.getRange("A2:A" + datasheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(values[0][0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
    if (range) {
      range.offset(0, 0, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    } else {
      datasheet.appendRow(values[0]);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)